# GL_CURRENT_VERTEX_ATTRIB - doc clarification

Tags: opengl

The [OpenGL 4 docs](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGetVertexAttrib.xhtml) says:

> GL_CURRENT_VERTEX_ATTRIB
>
> params returns four values that represent the current value for  the
> generic vertex attribute specified by index. Generic vertex  attribute
> 0 is unique in that it has no current state, so an error  will be
> generated if index is 0. The initial value for all other  generic
> vertex attributes is (0,0,0,1).

What does it mean in practice that "an error will be generated if index is 0" ?

Let's assume that I have a vertex shader with the following layout:

```
layout (location = 0) in vec3 pos;
```

I want to set a generic(constant) vertex attribute.
Can I use glVertexAttrib3f with an index which is equal 0 ?

```
glVertexAttrib3f(0, 1, 0, 0);
```

Later I would like to check the current vertex attribute this way:

```
glGetVertexAttribfv(0, GL_CURRENT_VERTEX_ATTRIB, data);
```

Is it correct ?

Comment: *"[...] Generic vertex attribute 0 is unique [...]"* - Can you please show where you found this sentence in the specification?? (most recent: [OpenGL 4.6 API Compatibility Profile Specification](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.compatibility.pdf) )

Comment: @Rabbid76: https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGetVertexAttrib.xhtml

Comment: @BDL ... but this is not the specification. I cannot find this part in the specification. (10.5 Vertex Array and Vertex Array Object Queries)

Comment: @Rabbid76: I also can't find it in the spec. Strange that it's mentioned in the docs though.

Comment: "*I want to set a generic(constant) vertex attribute.*" That's not a thing you should *want* to do. It's best to pretend that these APIs just don't exist.

Comment: As a small side note: the source of that statement in the ref pages can be found in the [GL 2.0 spec](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec20.pdf) (page 259): " The query `CURRENT VERTEX ATTRIB` returns the current value for the
generic attribute index. In this case the error `INVALID OPERATION` is generated
if index is zero, as there is no current value for generic attribute zero." The special treatment of attribute index 0 was modified multiple times between 2.x and 4.x. And the ref pages are notoriously bad when it comes to sublte updates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The text in the documentation is incorrect, relative to core OpenGL 3.2 or above. In the core profile of OpenGL, attribute 0 has state and that state can be queried.

In the *compatibility* profile up to 4.5 (and all GL versions before 3.0), attribute 0 does not have state. 4.5 changed the compatibility profile to give attribute 0 state. Indeed, the specification specifically calls this change out:

> This is a change in behavior of the compatibilty[sic] profile for increased interoperability with core profile and OpenGL ES.

That all having been said, you really should just pretend that the generic attribute values don't exist. Since they are so rarely used, their performance characteristics are unknown. And the values of them are somewhat ephemeral; if you set a value, render something, then render something that uses an array for that attribute, the value you previously set will not be preserved, requiring you to set it again. This is quite unlike most OpenGL state.